# What is a recommended way to manage git patch queues in unrelated repositories

Tags: git, github, version-control, mercurial

So, I have many repositories I need to manage patchsets in git.

I primarily work on what I'll call `issue-branches` (Unsure if thats an official terminology for git, but its short-lived branches for each issue). I do have a habit of rebasing if they end up taking longer to iron out, or even squashing if I have trial-and-error commits involved.

I come from a mercurial workflow with "MQ" as my "I'm comfortable" in which I do something, roughly like:

```
for i in $LIST_OF_REPO_PATHS_ON_DISK; do
    echo $i
    hg -R $i qseries
done
```

This is ultra simplied where I make the repos more readable, and don't echo anything if there is no patches in my queue.

The premise here is that I take out not-upstreamed things that I am no longer working on, or are rejected.

In git however, a branch is the used method, so I can't just do "git branches" (since many repos have multiple used branches by in normal cases), but I'd like to do some sort of "branches which are ahead of master, or origin remote".

For me, all my repos are on github, but not the upstream of all these repos (some upstreams are on gitolite hosted elsewhere). My github fork can be assumed to contain all my working branches copies, I also configure a "pr" remote in repos I also manage to track pull request heads, so i can easily checkout them locally without having to add a new, additional, remote.

Are there other ways to go about this problem of tracking my own work, if not is there a way to do what I want with git as described above.

For mercurial I wrote a blog post on *exactly* what I do: http://blog.drapostles.org/archives/126

Comment: What does have to do with `bash`?

Comment: you're right, not really much just that it can be scripted in bash. lets see if I can remove that tag...